# How to create BottomSheetDialogFragment using Navigation Architecture Component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, bottom-sheet, android-architecture-navigation

I am using **BottomSheetDialogFragment** for displaying few custom setting's.

**Requirement:**

When i click on any tab in BottomSheetDialogFragment i replace the fragment and add it to backstack so that when user click's onBackPress or Up action it should go back the the last setting's fragment of BottomSheetDialogFragment.

**I want to use Navigation Architecture Component to simplify my transaction's.**

Issue:
if i use Navigation Architecture Component to navigate from FragmentA to BottomSheetDialogFragment then i receive below error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: dialog must not be null
>   BottomSheetDialogFragment

*I don't know how to instantiate BottomSheetDialogFragment using Navigation Architecture Component and and using below code will not have a maintain backstack using Navigation Architecture Component.*

```
BottomSheetDialogFragment.show(FragmentManager manager, String tag)
```

Comment: Hello @anmol did you get any solution for this because i am trying to do the same

Comment: I tried doing it in a different way check out this demo project https://github.com/andor201995/NavigationDemo
@HemantSangle

Comment: Okay i will check the link

Comment: I will construct a proper answer and post here. @HemantSangle

Comment: That will be great

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In the navigation component version `2.1.0-alpha04`, `Navigation Graph` can contain `dialog` as one of the destinations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/startFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.awesomeproject.android.authentication.login.LoginFragment"
        android:label="Login"
        tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment" />

    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        android:name="com.awesomproject.android.BottomSheetFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_dialog_fragment" />

</navigation>
```

The BottomSheetFragment will look similar to other BottomSheet.

```
class BottomSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog_fragment, container, false)
}
```

Then you can treat `bottomSheet` the same way as other destinations. You can navigate to this destination or passing `safeArgs` in.

Cheers!

Comment: I tried this but when i try to navigate from dialog using navigation then NavController is missing can you share code of navigation from dialog to other fragment's or Dialog's? @Boonya

Comment: with this solution, the bottom sheet is being displayed in another fragment does not shadow the current fragment that call it

Comment: Oh man, it was scary when I added BottomSheet with navigation when it was opened in full screen. But you save my time. It was easy to just change dialog from a fragment.

Comment: @AndroLife do you happen to know the solution for that issue?

Comment: @AndroLife FWIW I'm seeing correct behavior with material 1.4.0 and navigation 2.3.5

Comment: @tir38 I get an issue with the navigation controller when I need to open 2 bottom sheets from the same fragment. One after another.

Comment: @tir38 Did you have an answer for this situation ? or used legacy approach ?